# Array of Labels

Tags: c#, .net

How to create array of labels with Microsoft Visual C# Express Edition ? Is there way to do it with graphical (drag'n'drop) editor or I have to manually add it to auto generated code ?

Comment: never change anything in generated code : your modifications would be overwritten by the designer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to manually add it.  But don't add it to auto generated code as it can be overwritten by Visual Studio designer.

I would add it in Load event handler for the form. The code can look like this:

```
Label[] labels = new Label[10];
labels[0] = new Label();
labels[0].Text = "blablabla";
labels[0].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100);
...
labels[9] = new Label();
...
```

PS. Your task seems a little unusual to me. What do you want to do? Maybe there are better ways to accomplish your task.

Comment: Thanks... I'm doing Turing Machine simulator. Those labels would represent part of the tape

Answer (score 7):

You can add the labels to the form using the GUI editor, then add those to the array in form load.

```
Label[] _Labels = new Label[3];
private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _Labels[0] = this.Label1;
    _Labels[1] = this.Label2;
    _Labels[2] = this.Label3;
}
```

This will at least make setting the location easier.  Also you might want to consider using the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9e8s203.aspx) if you're dynamically creating labels (or any control really).

Answer (score 0):

```
Label[ , ] _arr = new Label[4 , 4];

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
        _arr[i ,j] = new Label();
        _arr[i ,j].Text = ""+i+","+j;
        _arr[i ,j].Size = new Size(50,50);
        _arr[i ,j].Location = new Point(j*50,i*50);
        //you can set other property here like Border or else
        this.Controls.Add(_arr[i ,j]);
    }
 }
}
```

if you want to set Border of Label in C# maybe you should check
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx

Label have property called Border. Please check it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=0;
ControlNum=10;
Label[] lblExample= new Label[];
for(i=0;i<ControlNum;i++)
{
  lblExample[i] = new Label();
  lblExample[i].ID="lblName"+i;  //lblName0,lblName1,lblName2....

 Form1.Controls.Add(lblExample[i]);
}
```

xD ...

Joshit0..

Comment: You are using the wrong kind of brackets for the Label[] declaration line.  This code won't compile.