# Initialize array for storing labels

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, label

In my program, I have already made 10 labels in designing window and they are labelled as label 1, label 2,... and so on. I wanna perform some operation all these labels at once so I made an array to store these labels and then perform operation on array, as it will be easier to apply loop.
Can we apply loop to store these labels in to array, because if the labels are 50, it will be tougher to follow this strategy

```
Label[] labelArray = new Label[10];
labelArray[0] = label1;
labelArray[1] = label2;
labelArray[2] = label3;
labelArray[3] = label4;
labelArray[4] = label5;
labelArray[5] = label6;
labelArray[6] = label7;
labelArray[7] = label8;
labelArray[8] = label9;
```

Comment: WebForms?  WinForms?  WPF?  You need to include a [MCVE] with your question

Comment: If WinForms... `var labelArray = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToArray();`

Comment: If you are talking about an desktop app you can pick the collection of the controls in the form, iterate them and see if the property name start with label. If it starts with label insert in the array. If they are with the name like you refer in the example

Comment: @BlazeChill Also can be done with Linq: `this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(l => l.Name.StartsWith("label")).ToArray();`

Answer (score 2):

If the labels of interest all have something in common, e.g. they all have "label" in the name, or they have the same [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) (which would be a good property to use for this purpose), then you could simply use

```
//using System.Linq;
var list = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where
( 
    label => label.Name.Contains("label")     //Use these, or any other
          && label.Tag == "MyUniqueTag"       //properties, to find what you need
);
foreach (var label in list)
{
    DoSomething(label);
}
```

Also, see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962449/array-of-labels).

Answer (score 0):

For `Windows Forms` you can use:

```
List<Label> lbls = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();
```

and now, you have all your `lables` in a list.

You can get them by

```
foreach(var lbl in lbls){
    //var value = lbl.Text;
}
```