# Reading from file and adding text to the label control already available on the form

Tags: c#-3.0

I m new to c#.

I have a form with `20 labels` on it with names from `label1 to label20`.

I am reading a text file using streamreader line-by-line.

Now I want to associate the text from each line to the labels already available on the form, i.e.

```
Line 1 to label1
Line 2 to label2
Line 3 to label3 and so on...
```

Any help is really appreciable.
Thanks in advance.
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return an array of strings (zero based) which you can play with the index to assign to any label you want.

```
    string[] readFile = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

For example

> This is line 1
>
> This is line 2
>
> This is line 3

Returns

```
["This is line 1", "This is line 2", "This is line 3"]
```

So you can assign line 2 text to `Label2` for example

```
Label2.Text = readFile[1];
```

EDIT:

```
private void MyForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label[] MyLabels = new Label[3];

    MyLabels[0] = this.Label1;
    MyLabels[1] = this.Label2;
    MyLabels[2] = this.Label3;
}
```

Then you could do what you said

```
for (int i = 0; i < readFile.Length; i++)
{
    MyLabels[i].Text = readFile[i];
}
```

Comment: Sir the requirement is to associate the text to the label while we r reading to the end of file. Can't we do label[¡]=deadline[¡]

Comment: Yes you can. One posibility is to create dinamically your labels and pile them into an array. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962449/array-of-labels)

Comment: That I cannot do, as the labels are the part of the GUI already designed by someone..

Comment: Then you can reference all `Labels` into an array. Check the edit

Comment: Whatever answer you consider to be correct please mark it.